# Frobenius method for $xy^{\prime\prime} + y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I am to use the method of Frobenius to find a series solution of the ODE

$$xy^{\prime\prime} + y = 0$$

I have derived the indicial equation 
$$r^2 -r = 0$$
from which we see that either $r = 0$ or $r= 1$. We then propose the Frobenius series solution 
$$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{k+r}$$
and upon differentiation, we have
$$y^{\prime\prime}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-2}$$
and so substituting this into our ODE gives 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^{k+r}=0$$
which can also be written as
$$r(r-1)a_0x^{r-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kx^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k-1}x^{k+r-1}=0$$
Thus $a_0$ can be chosen arbitrarily so long as it satisfies certain conditions and, in general, for $n\geqslant 1$ we have the recurrence relation

$$(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n + a_{n-1}=0$$

The question is, how do I progress from here to obtain a series solution? The recurrence relation seems quite complicated so I am not sure that it is correct. I substituted the values of $r$ into this relation and I was a little discouraged by the number of factorials in there.

Comment: Aren't factorials a good thing?

Comment: I was just expecting something a little neater. If you can confirm that what I have so far above is correct, then that would be helpful.

Comment: To simplify the solving multiply the recursion by $(n+r-2)!(n+r-1)!$ and define $b_n = (n+r)!(n+r-1)!a_n$ to get $b_n + b_{n-1} = 0$

Comment: What did you manage to reduce the recurrence down to? (i.e. $a_n$ as a function of $a_1$ or $a_0$?